# How can I add an additional parameter to a button click EventHandler?

Tags: c#, eventhandler

In C#, how is the best way to add an additional property to a button event call?

Here is the code for the `EventHandler`:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
```

Here is the code for the `button_Click`:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

If I want to add a `PropertyGrid` parameter to the `button_Click` function parameters, how is the best way to do this?

I am wanting to do this as the `button.Click` code is in a function that has a `PropertyGrid` parameter, and in the `button_Click` function, I need to set the `PropertyGrid` selected object. This is only set when the `button.Click` button is clicked.

If I set the tag of the button to be a `PropertyGrid` object, how can I retrieve this tag object in the `button_Click` code?

The `button_Click` event is called from an object, and the sender is the object, that is not the button.

Can I please have some help with the code?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The button-click does not have this overload. But you are free to implement a method that takes a `PropertyGrid` which you can call from `button_Click`.

Comment: This can't be done, since the event handler's signature is already defined in the button's type. In your code, why couldn't you just call the new PropertyGrid() inside the event handler? Or, if the actual property grid to use is related to the button clicked, it could be related elsewhere (e.g. using the button.Tag property)

Comment: Why do you need to add an extra parameter? What problem does it solve?

Comment: _"the button.Click code is called from a function that has a PropertyGrid parameter"_ Why and how? That's not a _function_ but an event. And an event is triggered and not _called_. Why doesn't the function just call a method and passes the `PropertyGrid` as parameter? You don't need this button-click event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot convince a Button that it should know anything about a PropertyGrid.  When it fires its Click event then it can only tell you about what it knows.  Which is cast in stone.

You trivially work around this by using a lambda expression, it can capture the PropertyGrid argument value and pass it on to the method.  Roughly:

```
    private void SubscribeClick(PropertyGrid grid) {
        button.Click += new EventHandler(
            (sender, e) => button_Click(sender, e, grid)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That is the code that I was working towards, and it works correctly.

Comment: Hans, great answer, but the question must surely be a duplicate.

Comment: Probably, godspeed trying to find it back.  This is a [regex] question.